# Facebook - upload and tag picture (through the C# SDK)

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a 'Page Tab' application in Facebook using C#.NET. In this application the user can upload a picture to the feed of the page the application belongs. The user should get automatically tagged in the picture.

I already have the code to upload the picture to the wall, but every attempt to get the user to get tagged doesn't seem to work. 
Here is the code I'm currently using to upload a picture to my wall.

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("url", "<url to image>");
parameters.Add("message", "Message to go with the picture");
parameters.Add("access_token", "<access_token of page this application belongs to>");
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient("AccessToken");
client.Post("https://graph.facebook.com/page_ID/photos", parameters);
```

But how do I tag the user in this picture? I assume the user should log in to my application and I should then use the 'user id' somehow. But the attempts I made don't seem to work at all.

One of the things I tried is tagging myself by directly inserting my own 'uid' in the code, like this:

```
parameters.Add("tags", new object[] { 
    new Dictionary<string, object>(){
        {"tag_uid", "<My own user id>"}, 
        {"x", "0"},
        {"y", "0"},
    }
});
```

I also tried stuff like this:

```
var tags = new[] {                        
    new { tag_uid = "<My own user id>", x = 0, y = 0 }
};
parameters.Add("tags", tags);
```

And even

```
var tags = new[] {                        
    new { tag_text = "testing", x = 0, y = 0 }
};
parameters.Add("tags", tags);
```

If I go to the 'Graph API Explorer' and try it out there, then I also get an error message:

> {
>          "error": {
>              "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
>              "type": "OAuthException", 
>              "code": 1
>          }
>      }

But all those only results in the error: "OAuthException - #1) An unknown error has occurred.". If I comment out the tagging part everything seems to work perfectly. So how do I get the user ID and then tag him in the picture I'm uploading?

Answer (score 1):

To add tags, you need to make separate call using the tags endpoint. Here is the documentation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/tags/

Scroll down to see the sample calls. In php it is something like this:

```
    * make the API call */

    $response = $facebook->api(
      "/{photo-id}/tags",
      "POST",
      array (
        'tags' => '[{\'tag_text\': \'Testing\'}]',
      )
    );

    /* handle the result */
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately when I try it by using the photo-id then I still get the same error message. I even tried it using the Graph API Explorer, but still end up getting that error message. I updated my question to include the 'Graph API Explorer' error message.

Comment: From what I can see in your code, you're adding the tags in parameters. Did you try the separate call as I mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, I send the picture to facebook, get the photo-id from the response, and then use the photo-id to add tags to the picture. But even with the 'Graph API Explorer'-page it keeps giving the error message.

Comment: Nathan, I just tried it with Graph API and it works. I posted "tag_text: Testing" to <picture_id>/tags. In my Case, the picture already exists. Can you describe your case?